# Spring Boot + Angular: required parameter is not present

Tags: angular, spring-boot

In my project, on the client side, in angular I use the following code to perform a POST request and pass an array of objects to the server, based on Spring Boot.

```
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );

    var params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params.set("allQuestions", JSON.stringify(this.dataSource));

    this.http
      .post("/questions/import", params, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.dialog.close(true);
        },
        (error) => this.displayErrorMessage(error)
      );
```

On the server (Spring Boot), there's a method to receive this request:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/questions/import", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
 public ResponseEntity<String> importQuestions(@RequestParam("allQuestions") Question[] allQuestions) { ...  }
```

Upon making POST request from the client, I get the following error on the server-side:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Question[] parameter 'allQuestions' is not present]

I do not understand why does this error appear. I've passed "allQuestions" parameters in HttpParams class instance on the client side.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like

```
this.http
      .post("/questions/import", undefined, { headers: headers, params })
```

By the way if you are sending a json body in spring boot you should use @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam because @RequestParam is for queryparameters. and send the request like :-

```
this.http
          .post("/questions/import", this.dataSource, { headers: headers})
```

Answer (score 1):

when sending from angular a post request the body must be of type string.

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );

    let params: string = JSON.stringify(this.dataSource);

    this.http
      .post("/questions/import", params, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.dialog.close(true);
        },
        (error) => this.displayErrorMessage(error)
      );
```

The second issue you have is that with post request in spring you expect @RequestBody and not @RequestParam as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/questions/import", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json")
 public ResponseEntity<String> importQuestions(@RequestBody Question[] allQuestions) { ...  }
```